# Way to shrink Resources folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, resources

I have 100 pictures in my Resources folder and they can really be annoying when trying to find some other resource. Is there a way I could "create another resource folder" to put the 100 pictures in?

Or do I just have to deal with scrolling and scrolling when trying to find another resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put files wherever you want in your project-- `Resources` is just a default folder that gets created for you. You could create a sibling folder to Resources, or a subfolder inside of it.

You can do this in two ways: One by right clicking on the project and creating a new group for the images. This will create the logical folder, but won't actually create a subdirectory on disk. If you want the layout on disk also, create the folder on the command line or with Finder and then drag it into Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with @quixoto ans,

one thing more you can categories your folders according to any visible form.And use proper hierarchy for folders.because when you having number of folder and files then this necessary to make hierarchy also naming conventions are necessary for quick understanding and quick search. (e.g. Make images folder for images and in this folder sub folders, for backgrond image,button images,tab images etc.).so it helps you in quick search.